# Java Package Won't Compile

Tags: java, collections, compiler-errors, package

I think my understanding of how to set up a Java package might be missing something because I cannot get my package to compile. I have 3 class files. My directory looks like this: ...Documents\jsjf which contains: ArrayStack.java and StackADT.java. Within the jsjf directory I also have a folder "EmptyCollectionException" which contains EmptyCollectionException.java.   I can compile EmptyCollectionException.java and StackADT.java but when I try to compile ArrayStack.java I get the following error messages (see link): https://i.stack.imgur.com/koJ8P.jpg

Here is the top part of each part of my code for each file. Does anyone know what the problem is here. Why is ArrayStack not able to import the package?

For ArrayStack.java

```
package jsjf;



import jsjf.EmptyCollectionException;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ArrayStack<T> implements StackADT<T>
{
   private final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 100;
   private int top;
   private T[] stack;



   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Creates an empty stack using the specified capacity.
   // Note top is now initialized at -1 so that when first
   // element is added an top is decremented, top will equal 0
   // corresponding to the array index of the first element.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public ArrayStack(int initialCapacity)
   {
      top = -1;
      stack = (T[]) (new Object[initialCapacity]);
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Creates an empty stack using the default capacity.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public ArrayStack()
   {
      this(DEFAULT_CAPACITY);
   }


//Rest of code.......
```

For EmptyCollectionException.java:

```
package jsjf.exceptions;


public class EmptyCollectionException extends RuntimeException
{
    /**
     * Sets up this exception with an appropriate message.
     * @param collection the name of the collection
     */
    public EmptyCollectionException(String collection)
    {
        super("The " + collection + " is empty.");
    }
}
```

For StackADT:

```
package jsjf;


public interface StackADT<T>
{
    /**  
     * Adds the specified element to the top of this stack. 
     * @param element element to be pushed onto the stack
     */

    //Rest of Code
```

Comment: Please post text, not links to images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, a package name should not start with an upper case. It would have helped you to see that `jsjf.EmptyCollectionException` does not point to a class in your hierarchy but to a package. Therefore, after renaming the package according to the Java naming conventions, the correct import should be :

```
import jsjf.emptyCollecionException.EmptyCollectionException
```

In you exception class, you use another package name (`exceptions`). The package name should match the name of the parent directory. Therefore, I woul rename the directory containing `EmptyCollectionException` to `exception` and fix the import in `ArrayStack`.

Finally, I strongly recommend you to work with an IDE when you will have compiled some classes manually just to know how it works. An IDE will help you with the imports, compilation, and lots of other things

Answer (score 1):

Your code is saying you expect `EmptyCollectionException` to be in the package `jsjf`, but you say that class exists in a subfolder, which would be deeper in the package hierarchy (and counter to Java naming conventions, where package names usually aren't camel-cased).

Your `EmptyCollectionException` class code says it's in the `jsjf.exceptions` package, meaning (a) it should be in the `exceptions` folder under the `jsjf` folder, and your import of `EmptyCollectionException` should be `import jsjf.exceptions. EmptyCollectionException`.

You also need to be in a reasonable place when you compile, e.g., your documents folder since packages would live "underneath" where you're compiling from. Personally, I'd put  this into a more reasonable folder location, preferably without spaces, somewhere not under a Windows documents folder.